# I want to change the role field in devise sign up dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

In my user model i add

```
ROLES =  Role.all.collect(&:name)
```

In my view part of sign up in

```
<% if can? :manage, @users %>
<p><%= f.label :role %>: <%= f.collection_select :role, User::ROLES, :to_s, :humanize, {:include_blank => true} %></p>
<% end %>
```

The problem is  ROLES =  Role.all.collect(&:name) is not updated when i add and edit . For example i add new role user then i have to restart the server to see the changes in the role inside the signup field. How can i update the changes in role without restart the server?

Comment: Why you are using ROLES constant? that will fetch role records only once, when your user model is loaded, thats why its not updated. Instead, you can use, directly Role.all.collect(&:name) in your view. So it will fetch role records everytime its loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I want what i get but now i get problem in editing. I want to send the id of role rather than the name so that if the name of role is edited then the role given to the user is also edited. i ask this question in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681227/how-to-change-the-role-name-as-we-edit-the-name-of-role-in-devise May you help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the simple solution

```
<% if can? :manage, @users %>
  <p><%= f.label :role %>: <%= f.collection_select :role, Role.all.map(&:name), :to_s, :humanize, {:include_blank => true} %></p>
<% end %>
```

You can also place this in a helper, or let the controller handle the retrieving of the roles (e.g. set a instance variable `@roles`).

So in short: do not use a constant :)

Comment: Here i want to save the id of role name in database so that if first the role is guests is involve to many user. Later on if admin edit the guests to guest then problem occurs. so <%= f.collection_select :role_id,User::roles, :id, :name ,:prompt => 'Select Role'%> like this to work. How can i do?

Comment: From the original question the problem was that the constant `ROLES` is not updated. Adding a new role does not update the constant. So do not use a constant. Did you try this? Or please clarify your original question.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I want what i get but now i get problem in editing. I want to send the id of role rather than the name so that if the name of role is edited then the role given to the user is also edited. i ask this question in here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681227/how-to-change-the-role-name-as-we-edit-the-name-of-role-in-devise May you help me.

Answer (score 1):

Use a class method instead of a constant:

```
def self.roles
  Role.all.collect(&:name)
end
```

Of course, this is provided for free if `user` has many `roles`.

Comment: Here i want to save the id of role name in database so that if first the role is guests is involve to many user. Later on if admin edit the  guests to guest then problem occurs. so <%= f.collection_select :role_id,User::roles, :id, :name ,:prompt => 'Select Role'%> like this to work. How can i do?