# how to change the role name as we edit the name of role in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

I have model user from devise

```
 belongs_to :role
```

Here i want to save the id of role name in database so that if first the role is guests is involve to many user. Later on if admin edit the guests to guest then problem occurs. so

```
<% if can? :manage, @users %>
<%= f.collection_select :role_id,Role.all, :id, :name ,:prompt => 'Select Role'%> 
<% end%>
```

like this to work. How can i do?  as i did like this in other model but in user model of devise it its not working,

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by `not working`? Do you get an error? Do you know which view to adapt?

Comment: can can is not working when i do belongs_to :role in user.rb. It means it is not giving acces  role admin .. and it gives error undefined method `role_id' for #<User:0x007f61d05ee820>

Comment: Heve you created a migration to add the column `role_id` to user? Did you run `rake db:migrate`?

Comment: Since i am using Mongodb as database i need not to do that